# (MVC 2) How to return some part (DIV) of VIEW or complete VIEW after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to refresh a grid of VIEW after ajax call.

How can I do that ?

I tried below :

```
                   $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Report/GetFinancialTransactions",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                var mydata = $(data).find('.innermain');
                                $('.innermain').html(mydata.html());
                            }
                        });
```

In Controller :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFinancialTransactions()
    {
        var FinancialResult = _webCCrRepository.FinancialTransactions();
        return View("FinancialTransactions", FinancialResult);
    }
```

Alert is showing undefined.

Comment: you might have a server side error/exception. If you use Firefox or Chrome you can examine the ajax request/response to check if the response is HTTP 500 or some other error . With Firebug extension you can see the request/response in the "console" tab .

Comment: Yes, I checked from firebug and its working fine.
Also , after ajax response page is refreshing which should not happen.

Comment: In your controller action , you might need to check if it is a ajax request using Request.IsAjaxRequest()  . If it is from ajax , then return PartialView instead of View .  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050894/how-to-call-an-actionresult-from-jquery

Comment: I added partial view and its working now. Thanks a lot friend