# mvc ajax return partial view with model get the value of model in the success

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax that return partial view with strongly type
I want in the success to get the values of the model.
is it possible?
the code return:

```
return View("Test", Model);
```

in the ajax:
I want to get the model in the data varible

```
 success: function (data) {
       data.
           }
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050894/how-to-call-an-actionresult-from-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201617/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-actionresult-method-in-controller-and-return-data as they both address your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Partial View would need to return JSON data for you to be able to access the data like that.

In your controller (I'm assuming this is a HTTPPost call):

```
return Json(new { id = 1, name = "Test" });
```

In your JS Ajax call:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.name); //alerts 'Test'
}
```

**update**
OK, if you want to have the Partial View returned and the model, you could return the View as you already are then convert the model to a JSON string to be accessed and used in JS in the View maybe? Here's a rough example...

so in Controller:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
...
var jsonstring = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model); 
...
ViewBag.JsonString = jsonString;
```

then in the Partial View:

```
@{
   var jsonString = ViewBag.JsonString;
}
<script>
var data = JSON.parse("@jsonString");
alert(data.name); //alerts 'Test'
</script>
```

Comment: hi, thank you but I need to return the partial view and the model, in your example how do I use in the partirl view?

Comment: do you have `@{
   var jsonString = ViewBag.JsonString;
}` at the top of your Partial View (before the `<script>` tag)

Comment: i did it, but I get the error because the script is in the main view , and it doesnt know the partial, do you have any idea?

Comment: you'll need to put that script in the partial and execute JS from there.

Answer (score 0):

No, for that you need to return `JsonResult` back from controller action which would be like:

```
return Json(new {response =  Model });
```

Now it ajax success, you can access the result from json object which is returned :

```
success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is Ajax form

```
OnSuccess = "ShowMessage()"
```

and script is

```
    <script>
    function ShowMessage() {
                document.getElementById('info').value='YOUR_MESSAGE';
                setTimeout(function () {
                $("#info").hide();
                }, 3000);
            }
    <script>
```

and Your Html tag should be like this

```
<div id="info"></div>
```